# How do I get a handle to a process in Visual C++?

Tags: visual-c++

I opened up a process using CreateProcess (calc.exe in this case).

I passed the parameters to createProcess:

```
L"<path to calc>",
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
false,
NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
NULL,
NULL,
&<startupInfo struct memset to 0>
&<procInfo struct memset to 0>
```

I'd like to be able to kill the process, open threads in that process, etc. I know the calls to do so but they require handles, which I don't have.

Is there a way to automatically open a handle to a child process when spawning it, or something else?

I was thinking th e'inherit handles' parameter in CreateProcess but that doesn't seem quite right.

Comment: **MSDN** is the `goto` place for such RTFM questions, not **StackOverflow**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The final argument you pass to `CreateProcess` is a pointer to a [PROCESS_INFORMATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms684873%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure (that's your `procInfo` variable).

On successful return from `CreateProcess`, that structure will be populated with the `HANDLE`'s you need. Specifically, it will contain the following:

> **hProcess**
>
> A handle to the newly created process. The handle is used to specify
>   the process in all functions that perform operations on the process
>   object.
>
> **hThread**
>
> A handle to the primary thread of the newly created process. The
>   handle is used to specify the thread in all functions that perform
>   operations on the thread object.
>
> **dwProcessId**
>
> A value that can be used to identify a process. The value is valid
>   from the time the process is created until all handles to the process
>   are closed and the process object is freed; at this point, the
>   identifier may be reused.
>
> **dwThreadId**
>
> A value that can be used to identify a thread. The value is valid from
>   the time the thread is created until all handles to the thread are
>   closed and the thread object is freed; at this point, the identifier
>   may be reused.

As [MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Handles in **PROCESS_INFORMATION** must be closed with **CloseHandle**
>   when they are no longer needed.

Comment: Ah! Thank you very much. so <struct>.hProcess will contain everything I need.


Thanks!

I don't have enough points to 'up' your comment :( I'll mark it as correct in ~5 minutes. Thanks

Comment: +1 for nice formatting and patience to answer such an obvious question instead of being rude like me. :)